# Menu with associated models and how to use 'Eager Loading' approach in a menu item issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, nosql

I want to make a rollOver menu for my project's main page. This will be shown in all pages of the site. Main menu items are `SHOWS` and `PROGRAMS`. When someone rolls over those buttons, all programmes will be listed inside a popping up div. (Program is name of my model and it's a general name I use for both shows, movies, tv programs etc.)

Now...

Here are my associations:

### Program.rb

```
class Program 
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :title
  field :content

  belongs_to :program_category

end
```

### program_category.rb

```
  class ProgramCategory 
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

    field :title
    field :content

    has_many :programs

  end
```

I need to get `program.title`s to show inside my menu. Like this:

```
SHOWS         PROGRAMS
  \- Lost        \- Ellen
  \- Dexter      \- Marta Stuart
  \- Alf         \- Jey Leno Show
```

Well... I'm doing this like this now:

### home_controller.rb

class HomeController < ApplicationController

```
 def index
     @menu_programs = Program.all.where(program_category_id: "50a7c373ce3a6bcc0a000006").limit(10)    #Yes, i think it's lame too...
     @menu_shows = Program.all.where(program_category_id: "50a67f36ce3a6b840d000007").limit(10) # And yes I'm using MonoDB and Mongoid
  end
```

Yeah... They are `program_category_id`s and very hard coded!!

I feel like...

This is not the best practice!

### QUESTION is:

What is best practice to show menu items from associated models? I heard somethign called 'Eager Loading' can someone explain it please? Because of n + 1 problem I have 36 queries...

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of `What is best practice to show menu items from associated models?` question is:

Using [Fragment Caching](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html), I think. It's even more essential than eager loading IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

its very simple, just use

```
 @menu_programs = Program.where(program_category_id: "50a7c373ce3a6bcc0a000006").include(:program_cateory).limit(10)
 @menu_shows = Program.where(program_category_id: "50a67f36ce3a6b840d000007").include(:program_cateory).limit(10)
```

please pay attention, I've removed .all from your query.

Comment: Err.. Its includeS I guess? This did not reduce query count. Nevertheless, it added 2 more queries. There were 21 queries now I have 23 queries :\

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. Only four queries are needed to execute above statement. The remaining 20 queries might be because of some other association which you might be calling in your view. And I made one mistake its 'includes' instead of 'include'